# C# JSON Parsing result seems to be null

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm currently making a simple program that uses an Advice API. The idea is that when someone pushes the button, a string of advice will appear. However, I have an issue where I can print the raw JSON responce but not the individual string of advice itself.

The labels are just for debugging purposes.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

```
public void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiURL).Result;
    string rawtext = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    label2.Text = rawtext;

    Todo todo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Todo>(rawtext);

    label1.Text = todo.advice;
}

public class Todo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string advice { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:

```
{"slip": { "id": 101, "advice": "Alway do anything for love, but don't do that."}}
```

Comment: Please show the json.

Comment: Note: _[`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples) is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use._

Comment: The JSON has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a container class regarding to the json structure. Also I've fixed some `HttpClient` usage mistakes.

```csharp
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiURL))
    {
        string rawtext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
        label2.Text = rawtext;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Todo todo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Slip>(rawtext).slip;

            label1.Text = todo.advice;
        }
    }
}

public class Slip
{
    public Todo slip { get; set; }
}

public class Todo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string advice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Moseph suggestion: now the method is `async`, means that the UI will be responsive while data is loading (that's a good thing). To prevent clicking twice while button is executing it's code, disable the button at start and enable at the finish of the method.

Answer (score 0):

The ToDo is nested in `slip`, so you need a parent class.

```
Slip slip = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Slip>(rawtext);

public class Slip
{
    public Todo slip { get; set; }
}

public class Todo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string advice { get; set; }
}
```